# Java difference between two methods (generics)

Tags: java, generics

Consider the class hierarchy

```
public class A {
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("I am A");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class B extends A {
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("I am B");
    }
}
```

In a third class I have two different methods

```
private static void print(A input) {
}

private static <T extends A> void print2(T input) {
}
```

What is the "difference" between them?

I can both call them with an instance of `A` and all subclasses of `A`:

```
public class Test {

    private static void print(A input) {
        input.say();
    }

    private static <T extends A> void print2(T input) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        print(b);
        print2(b);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

P.S.: The difference between

```
private static void print(java.util.List<A> input) {
}
private static <T extends A> void print2(java.util.List<T> input) {
}
```

is clear!

Comment: Depends what the method does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well from a practical reason there is not so much difference there. 
You could call the second method by

```
<B>test2(new B());
```

It would fail then when you try to use is with an A

```
<B>test2(new A()); //Compile error
```

Although this does not make a big use for it.

However:
The generic declaration does make sence when you e.g. add the return-types.

```
public void <T extends A> T test2(T var) {
    //do something
    return var;
}
```

that you could call with:

```
B b = new B();
B b2 = test2(b);
```

while calling a similar method without generics would require a cast.

Comment: Thank you! Are there other differences?

Comment: Generics start getting interesting on class-level. On Method-level using polymorphism is often equal.